# Can I show rowContextMenu from a button doing a trigger to one function using tabulator pluggin?

Tags: javascript, tabulator

We have a tabulator column definition , where one of them is a button created by a formatter

```
{title:"input", field:"blank",   width:30,  frozen:true, responsive:0,formatter:customFormatter2}
```

Into formatter we create a button

```
var customFormatter2 = function (cell, formatterParams) {
    var $button=$('<button>').text('Hola')
    $button.click(function(){
         $(cell.getElement()).trigger('contextmenu')
    })

    return $button.get(0);
}
```

Also we have a rowContextmenu created into tabulator.

I want call to menu that tabulator shows when we do right click in any row.

I tried call a trigger from cell,from  row... and I dont know if the event is accessible ,or I dont know do it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't user jQuery often, but I believe the only thing missing is preventing the propagation of the click event after the `contextmenu` event, which hides the menu.  Something like this should work, but I also had to add pageX and pageY to my custom event, so that Tabulator could calculate where to display the menu.  I am not sure how I would do this in jQuery.

```
$button.click(function(event){
  event.stopImmediatePropagation();
  $(cell.getElement()).trigger('contextmenu');
});
```

Or without jQuery and definitely works,

```
function customFormatter(cell, formatterParams){
    const button = document.createElement('button');
    button.textContent = "Hola";
    button.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
        event.stopImmediatePropagation();
        const myEvent = new Event('contextmenu');
        myEvent.pageX = event.pageX;
        myEvent.pageY = event.pageY;
        cell.getRow().getElement().dispatchEvent(myEvent);
    })
    return button;
}
```

Here is a full example without jQuery.
https://jsfiddle.net/nrayburn/guxkw394/101/

Be careful with this.  Because we are creating a custom event, it doesn't contain all of the normal properties that a real event would.  If Tabulator starts relying on different event properties, it would break this code. (Maybe you could copy the original event from the click and pass those properties into the custom event.  Not really sure how to do that.)